# JavaScript code to zoom maps using mouse scroll

Tags: javascript, zooming

Please help me to write JavaScript code to zoom-in, zoom-out Google maps using mouse scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is incomplete. I'm guessing you're referring to Google Maps. If this is the case you need to call `enableScrollWheelZoom()` on your GMap2 object.